# Passport Renewal and Citizenship Issue-Nepal

Tags: passports, nepal

My mother has MRP passport (which is going to expire) with valid US visa. Now, she is going to renew her passport but the government office mentions that the citizenship number in her old passport is incorrect and the new one (which will be electronic passport) will have a different citizenship number. I think this will create problem in travel. Is there a way out for this? Can citizenship number be changed in original (old) MRP passport itself so as to match it with the new electronic passport? (Country: Nepal)

Comment: Why do you think change in citizienship number will create a problem in travel? Are you worried that this change would invalidate her visa?

Comment: Since she will need to carry two passports (old one with visa and new one) with her during travel, I am worried that the difference in citizenship number in the two passports might arise questions in the airport and lead her to not being allowed to travel.

Answer (score 1):

The US does not allow US visas to be transferred to another passport.

Your mother should take both passports.

It is the name on the passport that is important.

If you are concerned about the change in citizenship number, she can either take with her any documentation she has concerning the change or apply for a new visa on her new passport.

Comment: When applying for a new visa on her new passport, will she require giving interview again if her current visa (in old passport) has validity of around 2 years?