# Can a valid US visa be transferred from old, expired passport (machine readable passport) to new one (electronic passport)?

Tags: visas, passports, nepal

My mother's old passport (MRP) is going to be expired and we are in the process of creating a new passport (which will be electronic passport as per the government's policy change). So, I had two questions in mind:

1. Can a valid US visa in the old passport (MRP) be transferred to new passport (electronic)?
2. If she carries two passports with her during travel (old one with valid visa and new one), will the difference in type (one is machine readable and another is electronic) cause any issue during travel in the airport?
3. Given this case, does she need to apply for new US visa? Her US visa still has 2 years validity.

Country: Nepal

Comment: Nope, it does not. Actually this question is somewhat related to Passport Renewal and Citizenship Issue-Nepal (which is also the question I had posted). However, it does not completely answer the concern placed in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can a valid US visa in the old passport (MRP) be transferred to new passport (electronic)?

No.  A new visa can be issued in the new passport, but this is not necessary.  She can also use the visa in the old passport along with the new passport.

> If she carries two passports with her during travel (old one with valid visa and new one), will the difference in type (one is machine readable and another is electronic) cause any issue during travel in the airport?

No.  Sources note that the passport must be of the same "type," but this refers to the categorization of the passport as a normal passport, official passport, or diplomatic passport.  Whether the passport has an RFID chip or not isn't relevant.

> Given this case, does she need to apply for new US visa? Her US visa still has 2 years validity.

It is not necessary to apply for a new visa in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it.

Comment: Additionally, do you have any information on whether or not the difference in citizenship number in old and new passports will cause any issue during travel? Question posted in [Passport Renewal and Citizenship Issue-Nepal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171489/passport-renewal-and-citizenship-issue-nepal/171495#171495)

Comment: I have been denied boarding when having a Visa in (expired) passport A while using normal passport B without a visa. One difference is that A and B were issued by different countries, as I have dual citizenship.

I had to re-apply for a USA visa in order to travel

Comment: @MartinEpsz indeed, the passport must be of the same type and issued by the same country.  From the US [foreign affairs manual](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html): "The nationality, as indicated in the new passport, must be the same as that shown in the passport bearing the visa foil."